# Needing to typecast

Tags: objective-c, ios

I have a class with an initializer that takes a NSDictionary:

```
-(id)initWithVector:(NSDictionary *) vectorDictionary;
```

when i try to pass it a NSDictionary, its giving me an error:

> Incompatible point types sending'VectorClass * _strong' to parameter
>   type 'NSDictionary *'

code:

```
// myVectorList is an array of dictionaries
for (NSDictionary *vector in self.myFielder.myVectorList)
{
    if ([vector isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]])
    {
        // hardcoded for testing purposes 
        if ([[vector objectForKey:HANDLE] isEqualToString:@"pt07p48u17aj75qx8n2fri9jlkrc262yt8"])
        {
            // GET THE WARNING ON PASSING "VECTOR"
            VectorClass *vector = [[VectorClass alloc] initWithVector:vector];

            [vector retrieveVectorAttributeTable];
            [vector retrieveVectorMetadataTable];
        }
    }
}
```

if i typecast (NSDictionary *)vector, no warning.

vector should be a dictionary, so why am i getting the warning?

Comment: funny how you thought that it was a good idea to use the very same name for two entirely different variables.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You use the same name for two different variables. The inner most variable is of type `VectorClass` defined in the same line, so the compiler tries to pass it to the `init` method, instead, change its name:

```
VectorClass *vectorC = [[VectorClass alloc] initWithVector:vector];
[vectorC retrieveVectorAttributeTable];
[vectorC retrieveVectorMetadataTable];
```

Comment: You shouldn't feel dumb for that. Most programmers do this mistake at this stage or other. As @Till commented, you should avoid using the same variable name, it is confusing (for other programmers and yourself) and dangerous (it might end up in erroneous behavior and not a compile time error) .